# How does the Desktop Window Manager composite windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, dwm

How does window compositing in the DWM (Windows 7+) work? Does the DWM ask each window what it looks like, and then composites those together onto the window frame and then onto the desktop? (And if so, what API call does it make when it asks? Could you respond with garbage?)

Or does it know that "Window A" is made up of a textbox at (5, 10) that is colored red, and it knows how to draw it accordingly? If that's the case, is there a API to tell the DWM what a window has?

**Basically how does it go from an application (window) to what it draws on the screen? And what are the specific API calls (from the user app to the Windows DWM)?**

Comment: This is a broad subject, its unclear at what level you want an answer. [Painting the Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ff381401(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What's behind the question? I'm finding it hard to think of a scenario where these details would matter to an app developer.

Comment: Alex K. Looking for answers to the questions in bold at the end.

Comment: David Heffernan: I'm looking to capture/modify what gets sent to the DWM for rendering. Not sure exactly what the process is, so trying to learn that first.

Comment: @AlexK. is BeginPaint still how it's done in Windows 7+? I didn't know if new WPF applications used something newer than GDI.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Sounds like you haven't got the right solution to the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Trying to capture a screenshot of an occluded window. ScreenCapture functions only capture what's on the screen. Getting the device context and forcing the window to paint to an offscreen context with PrintWindow is not well supported after XP. Hoping that I can hook User32 to get the intermediary.

Comment: If I were you I'd ask about your goal rather than your solution, because I'm sceptical that your solution is actually viable

Comment: And having a distinct answer to this question would help me assess viability :)

Comment: The points we are trying to make are a) that an assessment of the viability can come as part of the overall discussion related to your end goal, and b) that there are other options that should also be tried first. You are asking for the entire Encyclopedia DWMitannica when in reality you only want volume Sa-Sc; let's focus on the problem you are trying to solve and we can solve your problem faster and with code that will be more robust. (The kind of fallacy that you have fallen into is a common problem called the "XY problem". If anyone comes off as abrasive, that is why.)

Comment: (Actually this is a variation of the XY problem that seems to be unique to Stack Overflow that I can best describe as "I want [this](http://img.labnol.org/di/wikipedia-print.jpg)" "You don't want that, your question shows you really want [only this](http://aircollection.org/part/MHS/MD-83_1/casc-club_MHSMD-83Rev%2011.jpg)" — I'm not sure whether it has a name, or if not, what to call it...)

Comment: Jason @andlabs makes good points. In any case, the question you asked is too broad and if you don't want to narrow the focus then I think it should be closed.

Comment: Do you really need answers to all those questions in order to use [DWM Thumbnails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541.aspx)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you guys think I'm not asking the question I want an answer to. I've already done enough research to know that there's not a built in function to do what I want to do. I need more information to figure out the next steps. @Iinspectable DWM Thumbnails does not work for windows that are occluded or partially off screen.

Comment: @Jason: DWM thumbnails is the implementation used to display the taskbar thumbnail preview images. They render for any window, visible partially occluded, or offscreen. Why do you assume that this API wouldn't work for those windows?

Comment: @Jason it's because they don't know the answer, very few people do. The fact it's been 6 years without an answer attests that fact

Answer (score 1):

`user32!CreateWindowExW` eventually calls `user32!NtUserCreateWindowEx`, which is a win32k syscall. It ends up calling `win32k!xxxCreateWindowEx`, which allocates a new  window (`tagWND`) on the user heap using `win32k!HmAllocObject`. This returns a handle integer into the global user handle table managed by win32k.

`win32k!xxxCreateWindowEx` then calls `win32k!DwmAsyncChildCreate`:

[image]

`win32k!DwmAsyncChildCreate` constructs a LPC `_PORT_MESSAGE` message and inserts the parameters of the call into the message. `Object` is the DWM ALPC port, `a2` is the window handle `hWND`, `a3` is the thread desktop window handle.

[image]

LPC is now implemented internally using ALPC, and can be synchronous or asynchronous, but in this case, the message is sent asynchronously.

dwm.exe has a port thread that waits on the port. The thread continually runs in `CPortBase::PortThreadInternal`, calling `NtReplyWaitReceivePort` on the ALPC port it created, and when it receives a message, it calls `CPortBase::RoutePacket`.

Several messages are sent to DWM, including when the window is shown or hidden.

Seeing as DWM has access to the hWND, it can get the device context (`((PDCE)Wnd->pcls->pdce)->hDC`), and then the surface from the `_DC` structure (`DC->dclevel.pSurface`). On a virtualbox win7 VM, it appears to be an engine managed surface because very few calls are made to cdd.dll, and on `ShowWindowEx`, `win32k!hsurfCreateCompatibleSurface` calls `cdd!DrvCreateDeviceBitmapEx`, which returns unimplemented, so then `win32k!hsurfCreateCompatibleSurface` instead calls `win32k!SURFACE::bCreateDIB` to create the surface. In this call, the surface object is inserted into GDI handle table (though it is at a kernel address, the kernel address range is mapped to different physical pages for each process) using `HmgInsertObject`. The handle `HBITMAP` appears to be a handle to the `_BASEOBJECT` of the `SURFACE` object, and the `SURFACE` object contains an embedded `_SURFOBJ`, which points to the first scan line of the bitmap via `pvscan0`. `HSURF` and `HBITMAP` appear to be the same.

The `_DXGK_DRIVERCAPS` structure returned by `dxgkrnl!DxgkCddGetDriverCaps` is the same as the one on VboxMPWddm.cpp on github, so clearly it is returning the `_DXGK_DRIVERCAPS` of the WDDM display miniport driver:

[image]

It can be seen that at offset 0x34, the `_DXGK_PRESENTATIONCAPS` contains 0x3, meaning `SupportKernelModeCommandBuffer = 0` and therefore GDI is not accelerated.

It does appear to still pass some commands to dxgkrnl which then gets sent to the WDDM miniport, such as changing the pointer shape:

[image]

I'm not sure what happens when you have 2 screens and 2 display adapters and one supports GDI acceleration and the other doesn't.

I net debugged a windows 10 machine with an IGPU and something very different happened when creating a surface. This time `cdd!DrvCreateDeviceBitmapEx` creates a device surface:

[image]

`dxgkrnl!DXGDEVICE::CreateStandardAllocation` eventually results in calls to the display miniport driver.

The `_DXGK_DRIVERCAPS` this time is different, and `SupportKernelModeCommandBuffer = 1` :

[image]

Whereas on the VM the surface is in system memory, the device surface (pointed to by `pvscan0` of `_SURFOBJ`) is created in an aperture memory segment memory address accessible by the GPU. The surface is copied to VRAM and copied back again to the aperture memory. Whereas the CPU accesses the memory directly, the GPU accesses the system memory through the aperture.

cdd.dll appears to be a XPDM display miniport driver replacement for framebuf.dll that does not pass any of it to the XPDM GPU driver (video port, miniport pair; which used to be videoprt.sys, vgapnp.sys). Instead it passes some GDI stuff to the WDDM display miniport driver and the stuff that can't be accelerated to the GDI engine (the XPDM display driver).

DWM can then read this surface and can then convert it to a DirectX surface, composite, and then use the WDDM stack to display it to the screen.

I'm not sure about DirectX windows. I don't know much about DirectX workings, but I will update.

Comment: Thank you - this answer is great for going into the details that matter. There’s a dearth of information online about DWM’s internals.